# Install SSL certificate across cluster servers

Tags: ssl, jboss, cluster-computing

We have cluster setup with multiple nodes as below 
192.168.92.16
192.168.95.11
192.168.72.200

Now we want to install the one SSL certificate for all cluster nodes (maybe use selt-signed certificate by OpenSSL).

Is it possible? If not, any hints for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal to put SSL on every node in a cluster, as this adds maintenance overhead. Many organizations instead use an SSL proxy:

https://www.nginx.com/resources/deployment-guides/load-balance-jboss-application-servers/

However, internal security could also be a concern, and that's where encrypting all nodes might be good. Generate an openssl self-signed cert for each one. That is answered here: [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) and configure each jboss server with that certificate.

If you go the nginx proxy way, and the system is public-facing, you might want to get a cert for the SSL proxy using https://letsencrypt.org

https://caffeinatedcode.com/posts/lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

Comment: Thank you! let me try it